# Concluding three statements regarding $3$ real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> $\{a,b,c\}\in \mathbb{R},\ a<b<c,\ a+b+c=6 ,\ ab+bc+ac=9$
>
> Conclusion $I.)\ 1<b<3$
>
> Conclusion $II.)\ 2<a<3$
>
> Conclusion $III.)\ 0<c<1$
>
> **Options**
>
> By the given statements
>
> $\color{green}{a.)\  \text{Only conclusion $I$ can be derived}}$.
>
> $b.)\ $ Only conclusion $II$ can be derived.
>
> $c.)\ $ Only conclusion $III$ can be derived.
>
> $d.)\ $  Conclusions $I,\ II,\ III$ can be derived.
>
> $e.)\ $  None of the three conclusions can be derived.

$\quad\\~\\$

I tried $(a+b+c)^2=36 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2=18$

and found that $(a,b,c)\rightarrow \{(-1,1,4),(-3,0,3)\}$ satisfies the two conditions

$a^2+b^2+c^2,\ a<b<c $  but not this one $a+b+c=6$

I thought a lot but can't find any suitable pairs.

I look for a simple and short way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: But if to solve a system of Diophantine equations?  $$ \left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b+c=6x\\&ab+ac+bc=9x^2\end{aligned}\right. $$  But there is one number always turns negative.

Comment: I'm in the sign was wrong. There is a solution. This.  $$a=3p^2$$ $$b=3s^2$$ $$c=3(p+s)^2$$ $$x=p^2+ps+s^2$$  Or so.  $$a=4s^2$$ $$b=9p^2+6ps+s^2$$  $$c=9p^2-6ps+s^2$$  $$x=3p^2+s^2$$

Answer (score 3):

I shall show that only Conclusion I is correct. For a fixed $b$, we have

$a+c=6-b$ and $ac=9-(a+c)b=9-(6-b)b=(b-3)^2$.  Hence, the quadratic polynomial

$x^2-(6-b)x+(b-3)^2$ has two distinct real roots $x=a$ and $x=c$.  Therefore,

the discriminant $(6-b)^2-4(b-3)^2=3b(4-b)$ of this quadratic is strictly

positive (hence, $0<b<4$).  Furthermore, the roots of the quadratic are

$a=\dfrac{(6-b)-\sqrt{3b(4-b)}}{2}$ and $c=\dfrac{(6-b)+\sqrt{3b(4-b)}}{2}$.  As

$a<b<c$, we must have $\dfrac{(6-b)-\sqrt{3b(4-b)}}{2}<b<\dfrac{(6-b)+\sqrt{3b(4-b)}}{2} $, or equivalently,

$-\sqrt{3b(4-b)}<3b-6<+\sqrt{3b(4-b)}$.  Hence,

$\sqrt{3}|b-2|<\sqrt{b(4-b)}$, or $3(b-2)^2<b(4-b)$.  Ergo, $4(b-1)(b-3)<0$.

That means $1<b<3$.

Note that $b=2$ gives a solution $(a,b,c)=(2-\sqrt{3},2,2+\sqrt{3})$.

Consequently, Conclusions II and III are false.  In fact, we can prove that

$0<a<1<b<3<c<4$.  It might be a good exercise for you to show that $0<abc<4$.

Answer (score 2):

> $\{a,b,c\}\in \mathbb{R},\ a<b<c,\ a+b+c=6 ,\ ab+bc+ac=9$
>
> Conclusion I.) $1<b<3$
>
> Conclusion II.) $2<a<3$
>
> Conclusion III.) $0<c<1$

Let $\{p,q,r\}\in \mathbb{R}: a=\min(p,q,r),\ c=\max(p,q,r),
b=\max(\min(p,q),\min(q,r),\min(r,p))$.
Let's solve a system
\begin{align}
p+q+r&=6 ,\\
pq+qr+rp&=9
\end{align}
for $q$ and $r$ in terms of $p$:
\begin{align}
q(p)&=3-\frac{1}{2} p-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3p (4-p)},
\\
r(p)&=3-\frac{1}{2} p+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3p (4-p)}.
\end{align}
The solution suggests that
$0\le p\le 4$ (to ensure real values).

This diagram illustrates relationship between $p,q$ and $r$:

[image]

Analysis of $q(p)$ and $r(p)$ 
(boundary end extreme points)
shows that 
\begin{align}
a&=\begin{cases}
p,& 0<p<1\\
q(p),& 1<p<4
\end{cases}
\\
b&=\begin{cases}
q(p),& 0<p<1\\
p,& 1<p<3\\
r(p),& 3<p<4
\end{cases}
\\
c&=\begin{cases}
r(p),& 0<p<3\\
p,& 3<p<4\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

And

$0<a<1$

$1<b<3$

$3<c<4$:

[image]

so the answer is

> a.) Only conclusion I can be derived.